# How do I pass parameters to onClick function in Java?(Android app development)

Tags: java, android, onclick

I have a custom class that one of its parameters is a button, and I put an OnClick function in the class which is supposed to use external information in order to work. Since the function is triggered by a click on the phone and not by the main code, I don't know how to specify the information(for the parameters) to be taken. How do I do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The `onClick()` method has a `View` parameter. You can use `setTag()` on the view to store arbitrary objects you can access with `getTag()` in the click handler.

Answer (score 2):

You can tag the view with object, in the object, you can set what ever values you need.
Foe example, if you need to set integer 10,

```
setTag(10+"");
```

and inside the click,

```
button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int number = Integer.parseInt(v.getTag().tostring());
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add custom parameters to the onClick method, but you can create a custom class and add parameters to its constructor. Example:

```
private class MyClickListener implements View.OnClickListener {
    private String myParam;

    public MyClickListener(String param) {
        myParam = param;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        // do whatever you want
    }
}
```

If you have this class you can set the onClick listener the following way:

```
myView.setOnClickListener(new MyClickListener("test"));
```